# Microsoft Access Database Engine causing fatal communications error with Windows Process Activation

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the Access Database Engine Redistributable to read an Access database in my .net application and for some reason whenever I use a join to query data from the access database to fill a datatable it causes a fatal communications error with the Windows Process Activation Service. I can populate datatables without issue as long as there is only one table. As soon as I add just one join, I get the system error. There are no errors in my application to trap, the system error occurs and then the application stops processing. This is only happening on one server. My local computer doesn't seem to have this issue. I'm using the exact same redistributable on my local computer and the server. Two things boggle my thinking why does a join cause an issue and why does it cause a system error and doesn't push it up to the app? If I'm using a single table query, it works fine.

Steps to populate datatable:

```vb
accessConnection = New 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & 
    uploadedFileName & " '; Persist Security Info=False;")
accessDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Table1 INNER JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table1.PK = Table2.PK", accessConnection)
accessDtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
accessDataAdapter.Fill(accessDtSet) - Application fails here
accessView = accessDtSet.Tables("Locations").DefaultView
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but maybe try the following provider in your connection string:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this code works on my local machine and on other servers. It just doesn't work on this one and the only error is the system error given in my original post.